# Can a Postgres instance with many Databases become blocked across many/all Databases due to a Locking issue on 1 Database?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

I haven't seen any documentation around this; the high level question is, given we have a Postgres Instance (Hosted as a AWS RDS), which contains many Databases, can an issue with query execution and locking on one of the Databases cause an issue across the entire instance?

I am specifically looking for info around the query execution/locking - I appreciate that issues around memory / CPU usage could be shared as this is a shared resource.

Earlier today one of our databases had an issue where essentially, all query execution ground to a halt; upon further investigation it turned out that internally we had 8 'blocking' queries that were blocking cyclically (i.e. depended on each other to execute).

For some reason, not only did the affected DB become stuck, but so did other Databases on the instance - even those not within the lock cycle.

What parameters / constraints should we be aware of when sharing an RDS Instance between databases?

We are using AWS Postgres 11

Answer (score 3):

What you describe doesn't sound like locks in the database. If several processes block one another, that is called a *deadlock*, and PostgreSQL resolves it automatically by canceling one of the involved transactions.

So maybe there was some lock outside the database involved, or you simply forgot to commit a transaction, and you had a *live lock* in the database.

Now normally this will only affect a single database, because you cannot access objects in a database different from the one you are connected to. The only exception is if you have a lock on one of the *shared tables*: `pg_database`, `pg_authid`, `pg_tablespace` and `pg_shdepend`. But you must be doing something rather unusual that typically requires superuser privileges to do that. You don't have those privileges on a hosted database.

The upshot is: there is nothing to consider, and what you describe should not happen. You should investigate more closely what exactly causes such a hang.

Comment: Okay thank you - that makes sense.
I took a note of the queries that were involved in the deadlock; it seems most of them were metadata queries querying pg_catalog, pg_event_trigger, pg_collation etc. Only one was from the application - a insert column with a foreign key.

Do you know whether connection limits are shared over the databases? Or independent? (i.e. the max number of connections allowed to the RDS)

Comment: Thats probably global, but doesn't cause a hang.